# How to install elasticsearch on jelastic cloud?

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud, jelastic

I'm in a Jelastic Cloud and I'm trying to install ElasticSearch in my container.

How can I do this?

Comment: This would probably help: http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/06/07/running-elasticsearch-with-tomcat-on-jelastic/

Comment: The article is still actual. Some screenshots were updated. The solution is valid and very simple to use.

Comment: Thanks, the article were updated today, Jelastic notifyed my by e-mail about the update (I sent message there before post on Stack Overflow) Now its everything solved. Thanks Guys.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to contact us.

Comment: New blog article about Elasticsearsh at Jelastic is available:http://blog.jelastic.com/2016/03/03/data-index-inside-the-cloud-how-to-deploy-elasticsearch-at-jelastic/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to suggest you one more solution like [Jelastic Docker](https://docs.jelastic.com/dockers-overview).

1. Go to your dashboard and click''New environment' button
2. Choose Docker tab, type environment name and push "Select container"

[image]

3. Type "elasticsearch" into search field and press to magnifier

[image]

4. Choose the first item from the appeared list and the appropriate version from the drop-down menu you would like to install. For example, I will install v. 2.0.2 to show you how to upgrade Elasticsearch in future.

[image]

5. After this, you have to bind Public IP in order this application to work in proper way.

[image]

6. That's all. In a short time, you'll get ready-to-use environment based on Docker.
   Let's get response from elasticsearch, press "Open in browser" and add at the end of address field the default elasticsearch port:

`http://{environment name}.{hoster's domain name}:9200`

```
{
    "name": "Taurus",
    "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
    "version": {
        "number": "2.0.2",
        "build_hash": "6abf5d8e5b37c2735d8e2f110f9743c453f71e92",
        "build_timestamp": "2015-12-16T12:49:58Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "5.2.1"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

7. Now, as was promised, let's upgrade Elasticsearch to the latest version (2.2). To do this, just click "Redeploy" button opposite the appropriate docker.

[image]

8. Choose the latest version and click Redeploy
9. Just in few moments, you'll get the upgraded Elasticsearch application.

Comment: How do I add more nodes to cluster? 
How to backup and manage storage size? Is it possible to run environment without public IP?

Comment: There have been lots of ElasticSearch hacks and breaches recently. Is ES secure by default? Or do you need to set an admin password as part of this process?